# How to get rid of this white effect on the page when clicking the scroll top button

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm currently working on this website http://www.test.yanosp.com/, but when I click the Back to Top button on the bottom of the page, the page gets white. How do I get rid of it? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you edit the post and embed images with the mentioned behavior? Because the page can change and the link become useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inspected your pagetop__link class and found that in the "http://www.test.yanosp.com/wp-content/themes/lionmedia/style.css" file, where you define that class in the stylesheet, you have the following selector:

```
.pagetop__link:active::before {
   background:rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
   z-index:9999;
}
```

Get rid of the line `background:rgba(255,255,255,0.9);` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

remove .pagetop__link::before {position: fixed} solve the problem